# json+struts2 how can parse only datatab details

Tags: json, struts2

i having following json response.how can i parse the data table content

```
{
    "activeEnergy": null,
    "activeEnergyVal": null,
    "apparentEnergy": null,
    "apparentEnergyVal": null,
    "bCurrent": null,
    "bCurrentVal": null,
    "bLoadval": null,
    "bVoltage": null,
    "bVoltageval": null,
    "bload": null,
    "datatab": {
        "columnDescriptions": [
            {
                "customProperties": {},
                "id": "Date",
                "label": "Date",
                "pattern": "",
                "type": "TEXT"
            },
            {
                "customProperties": {},
                "id": "Month",
                "label": "Month",
                "pattern": "",
                "type": "TEXT"
            },

            {
                "customProperties": {},
                "id": "ApparentEnergy_KvAh",
                "label": "ApparentEnergy_KvAh",
                "pattern": "",
                "type": "NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "customProperties": {},
                "id": "Rload",
                "label": "Rload",
                "pattern": "",
                "type": "NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "customProperties": {},
                "id": "Yload",
                "label": "Yload",
                "pattern": "",
                "type": "NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "customProperties": {},
                "id": "Bload",
                "label": "Bload",
                "pattern": "",
                "type": "NUMBER"
            }
        ],
        "customProperties": {},
        "localeForUserMessages": null,
        "numberOfColumns": 18,
        "numberOfRows": 6,
        "rows": [
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "02",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "02"
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "00",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "00"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 11,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 11
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 10,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 10
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 1057,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 1057
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 1788,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 1788
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 1233,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 1233
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 1202,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 1202
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 1208,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 1208
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "customProperties": {}
            },

            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "05",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "05"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "08",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "08"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "2014",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "2014"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "23",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "23"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "00",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "00"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 11,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 11
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 11,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 11
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 11,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 11
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 253,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 253
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 254,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 254
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 255,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 255
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 3463,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 3463
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 2558,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 2558
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 4331,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 4331
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 2962,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 2962
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 2806,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 2806
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 2849,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 2849
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "customProperties": {}
            },

            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "07",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "07"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "08",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "08"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "2014",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "2014"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "00",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "00"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": "00",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "00"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 254,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 254
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 255,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 255
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 256,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 256
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 20,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 20
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 30,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 30
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 40,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 40
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 76,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 76
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "NUMBER",
                        "value": {
                            "null": false,
                            "objectToFormat": 0,
                            "type": "NUMBER",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "customProperties": {}
            }
         ],
         "warnings": []
     },
 }
```

Comment: where you want to parse on server side or client side ? please provide more information where you facing problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with ajax,give me little more infomation what want to do exactly.

```
   success : function(response){
               for(var i=0;i<response.datatab.columnDescriptions.length;i++){
                 alert(response.datatab.columnDescriptions[i].id);
                 alert(response.datatab.columnDescriptions[i].label);
                }
             }
```

Comment: i want take a datatable details to display graph.

Comment: i want take data table details to display graph using google visualization how can i do that plz help me.